# facebook opengraph, how to make customized queries?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to make a request to search for 'customized' things, like: Restaurants nearby (see screenshot here).[image]. 
Another example is: Music my friends like, in the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=694736855?fields=music), if I query music, I just get what I like, not my friends'. Any tip? tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**me/friends?fields=music**
will give you the music interests of your friends

and for nearby restaurants you will have to execute a complex query like

```
search?q=cafe&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000
```

Refer to this **[page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/)** for search types

Comment: tks, any info on the restaurants query.
Oh almost instantly you updated your answer, fantastic!